Can't turn text fields in a table into a link
I have a list of open opportunities that displays on the user profile. Here's the .cmp and the controller. The issue isn't in the js
<aura:component controller="MyOpenOpportunitiesController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Opportunities" type="Opportunity[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" default="[
        {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'AccountName', type: 'text'}
    ]" />
    <aura:attribute name="cardTitle" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="user" type="User" /> <!-- Add this line -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:card title="{!v.cardTitle}" iconName="standard:opportunity">
        <lightning:datatable data="{!v.Opportunities}" columns="{!v.columns}" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

Apex Controller
public with sharing class MyOpenOpportunitiesController {
    public class OpportunityWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountName {get; set;}

        public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity opp, String accountName) {
            this.opp = opp;
            this.accountName = accountName;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<OpportunityWrapper> getOpenOpportunities(String recordId) {
        List<OpportunityWrapper> wrappers = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        if (recordId != null) {
            System.debug('Record ID: ' + recordId);
            List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = :recordId AND IsClosed = false];
            for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
                wrappers.add(new OpportunityWrapper(opp, opp.Account.Name));
            }
            System.debug('Number of opportunities fetched: ' + opportunities.size());
        } else {
            System.debug('Record ID is null');
        }
        return wrappers;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getCurrentUserId() {
        return UserInfo.getUserId();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static User getUser(String userId) {
        return [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId];
    }
}

I want to make the opp names into link to that opp. I adjusted the code below, but now it just displays blanks cells in the name column (along with a fully populated table everywhere else)
<aura:component controller="MyOpenOpportunitiesController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}" />
    <aura:attribute name="Opportunities" type="Object[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" default="[
        {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'oppURL', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'opp.Name' }, target: '_blank'}},
        {label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'AccountName', type: 'text'}
    ]" />
    <aura:attribute name="cardTitle" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="user" type="User" /> <!-- Add this line -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <lightning:card title="{!v.cardTitle}" iconName="standard:opportunity">
        <lightning:datatable data="{!v.Opportunities}" columns="{!v.columns}" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true" />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

Apex Controller
public with sharing class MyOpenOpportunitiesController {
    public class OpportunityWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountName {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String oppURL {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String accountURL {get; set;}


        public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity opp, String accountName) {
            this.opp = opp;
            this.accountName = accountName;
            this.oppURL = '/' + opp.Id;
            this.accountURL = '/' + opp.AccountId;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<OpportunityWrapper> getOpenOpportunities(String recordId) {
        List<OpportunityWrapper> wrappers = new List<OpportunityWrapper>();
        if (recordId != null) {
            System.debug('Record ID: ' + recordId);
            List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Account.Name, AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE OwnerId = :recordId AND IsClosed = false];
            for (Opportunity opp : opportunities) {
                wrappers.add(new OpportunityWrapper(opp, opp.Account.Name));
            }
            System.debug('Number of opportunities fetched: ' + opportunities.size());
        } else {
            System.debug('Record ID is null');
        }
        return wrappers;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getCurrentUserId() {
        return UserInfo.getUserId();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static User getUser(String userId) {
        return [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId];
    }
}


I know you wrote that the issue is not in the Js, but difficult to tell, given that I would not know how you are populating the Opportunities attribute.

Also, please provide a screenshot of the current result.

I've linked one of my relevant answers to this question. Your problem in particular is { fieldName: 'opp.Name' }. Lightning datatable and treegrid cannot navigation relationships. You must move the opportunity data to the top level of the object. In other words, you must transform opp.Name into something that is at the top level, such as opportunityName. You should be able to use a getter for this: @AuraEnabled public String opportunityName { get { return opp.Name; } set; } in your OpportunityWrapper.

@sfdcfox Yeah you nailed it. I fixed it about an hour ago and then remembered I posted this. Thanks for the help though, either way.
